# How to use orWhere inside andWhere in a doctrine query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I would like to create a search in which you can select several cities and options like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE (`city_id` = 4 OR `city_id` = 5) AND (`option` = 1 OR `option` = 2)
```

How can i make this in Doctrine?

```
/**
 * @param CompanyAdminSearch $search
 * @return Query
 */
public function findVisibleQuerySupplierSearch(CompanyAdminSearch $search): Query
{
    $query = $this->findVisibleQuerySupplier();

    if ($search->getCity()->count() > 0){
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($search->getCity() as $k => $city){
            $k++;
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere($query->expr()->orX("company.city = :city$k"))
                ->setParameter("city$k", $city);
        }
    }

    if ($search->getOptions()->count() > 0) {
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($search->getOptions() as $k => $option){
            $k++;
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere(":option$k MEMBER OF company.options")
                ->setParameter("option$k", $option);
        }
    }

    return $query->getQuery();
}

private function findVisibleQuerySupplier(): QueryBuilder
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('company')
        ->andWhere('company.metier = :metier')
        ->setParameter('metier', true)
        ;
}
```

I try with orX but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` WHERE (`city_id` = 4 OR `city_id` = 5) AND ... `` can be rewritten to `` WHERE `city_id` IN (4, 5) AND ... `` That will greatly simplify your query builder and provide the same result.

You can now use :

```
if ($search->getCity()->count() > 0) {
    $citiesId = [];
    foreach ($search->getCity() as $city) {
        $citiesId[] = $city; // get the cities in an array
    }

    // no need to write $query = $query->...
    $query->andWhere("company.city IN (:cities)") // use IN clause
          ->setParameter(":cities", $citiesId);   // and bind the array as parameter
}
```

You can now apply the same logic for `option` and other stuffs

---

I don't know what `$search->getCity()` looks like, but I have the feeling you can just use

```
if ($search->getCity()->count() > 0) {
    $query->andWhere("company.city IN (:cities)")
          ->setParameter(":cities", $search->getCity());
}
```